Looking for term to describe a line of lights and optional glass panes that border the underside of building canopies

Some historical buildings include a canopy at the entrance to protect vehicles and/or entering and exiting pedestrians from the elements. In some cases, this canopy is bordered by a number of lights e.g. a row of light bulbs, each bulb shielded by a vertical, decorative pane of glass. Is there an architectural term that refers to this row of lights?

An interesting question but it would be better answered on an architecture forum as it is likely to have a technical name..

@Greybeard I believe the technical architectural term for the row of arches (not the lights in them, so this doesn't fully answer the question) is "arcade"; the more familiar meaning of the term arcade is a somewhat distant derivative.

Uninterestingly, they are called canopy lights. This includes those used under bridges, in tunnels, in arcades, and the like. They can be decorative or industrial.

An interesting question; I live in a neighborhood where every building has a canopy (or awning), and while most are cloth (soft/tensile), a handful are solid (permanent/structural), and a subset of these latter have the lights you describe. I've wondered the same myself.
A little Google sleuthing turns up marquee lighting, likely because these lights originate, and are likely still most common for theaters¹, as opposed to residential or otherwise non-theatrical buildings.

Marquee Lighting
From the California Energy Commission Building Energy Efficiency Standards (2016), REFERENCE APPENDICES / Joint Appendices / Appendix JA1 Glossary:

Marquee Lighting is a permanent lighting system consisting of one or more rows of many small lamps, including light emitting diodes (LEDs), or fiber optic lighting, attached to a canopy.


1: The marquee, of course, being the hard canopy and associated signage, lighting, etc, used to market and name the show(s) currently being performed (on in the case of movie theaters, being screened).

I'm not sure this is so. marquee lighting is typically , as you say, "one or more rows of many small lamps (more accurately, bulbs or LEDs)" rather than that shown. We are looking for the name of the fascia and the fact that it is illuminated: the nature of the light source is not really germane. OED gives Marquee: 2. Originally and chiefly U.S. A canopy projecting over the main entrance to a building; spec. such a canopy at a theatre, cinema, etc., on which details of the entertainment or performers are displayed. -- Thus the whole projecting structure - including the "cornice" is a marquee.
